# Can't open video saved on jetson xavier using OpenCV video writer

Tags: python, opencv, jetson-xavier

I possess a Jetson Xavier, and I'm able to access the camera through dev/video0 or GStreamer. However, when I try to save the video in AVI or MP4 formats, I'm unable to open it. Based on the video size, which is around 10-12 MB, I believe it should contain the frames. How can I properly save and reopen the video later?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

source = "/dev/video0"
gstr = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM) ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 "

# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstr, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('./output.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))

count = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)
        print(count)
        try:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            # cv2.imwrite("./log/"+str(count)+".jpg",frame)
        except:
            pass    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        count += 1
        if count >100:
            break        
    else:
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Build Info

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.5.0

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /opt/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     4.5.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-10-23T16:52:07Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.10.59-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.16.3
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    NEON FP16
      required:                  NEON
      disabled:                  VFPV3

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv hdf java js julia matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.1 interface 11101)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      YES (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcblas.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.4, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             72 87
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.2.6)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.4)
    install path:                lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: why would you expect "XVID" to be available? `out.isOpened()`? `cv.getBuildInformation()`?

Comment: out.isOpened() --> True

Comment: I tried XVID and mp4 what should I use?

Comment: if isOpened(), then that part should be okay. next: what's the value of `frame.shape`? what's the size of the video file after the script ran? what does `ffprobe` think about the video file?

Comment: I solved the problem by using fourcc_type = 'avc1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fourcc_type = 'avc1'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*fourcc_type)
```